# Scroll not working jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) { 
        $('header').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else{
        $('header').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});
});
```

Obviously I'm missing something.  it absolutely will not work in Wordpress.

Here is a link to my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SCATORY/0w1x3n43/5/.

Comment: in wordpress make sure there's `noConflict`

Comment: new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SCATORY/0w1x3n43/3/

Comment: @JasonSprague what's the problem you're facing in wordpress?? are you using GROVE  WordPress Theme??

Comment: @MostafaBaezid its a custom theme I developed, done of the jquery works

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined @Greg Burkett

Comment: You could try replacing all of the "$" in your code above with "jQuery", and completely remove the $ in the function($) block up top

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    //your code
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0w1x3n43/2/)